# Use a docker registry from the kubernetes cluster on which it is deployed

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have an on-prem kubernetes cluster and I want to deploy to it a docker registry from which the cluster nodes can download images. In my attempts to do this, I've tried several methods of identifying the service: a NodePort, a LoadBalancer provided by MetalLB in Layer2 mode, its Flannel network IP (referring to the IP that, by default, would be on the 10.244.0.0/16 network), and its cluster IP (referring to the IP that, by default, would be on the 10.96.0.0/16 network). In every case, connecting to the registry via docker failed.

I performed a cURL against the IP and realized that while the requests were resolving as expected, the tcp dial step was consistently taking 63.15 +/- 0.05 seconds, followed by the HTTP(s) request itself completing in an amount of time that is within margin of error for the tcp dial. This is consistent across deployments with firewall rules varying from a relatively strict set to nothing except the rules added directly by kubernetes. It is also consistent across network architectures ranging from a single physical server with VMs for all cluster nodes to distinct physical hardware for each node and a physical switch. As mentioned previously, it is also consistent across the means by which the service is exposed. It is also consistent regardless of whether I use an ingress-nginx service to expose it or expose the docker registry directly.

Further, when I deploy another pod to the cluster, I am able to reach the pod at its cluster IP without any delays, but I do encounter an identical delay when trying to reach it at its external LoadBalancer IP or at a NodePort. No delays besides expected network latency are encountered when trying to reach the registry from a machine that is not a node on the cluster, e.g., using the LoadBalancer or NodePort.

As a matter of practice, my main inquiry is what is the "correct" way to do what I am attempting to do? Furthermore, as an academic matter, I would also like to know the source of the very long, very consistent delay that I've been seeing?

My deployment yaml file has been included below for reference. The ingress handler is ingress-nginx.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: registry-pv-claim
  namespace: docker-registry
  labels:
    app: registry
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-registry
  namespace: docker-registry
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-registry
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: docker-registry
          image: registry:2.7.1
          env:
            - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR
              value: ":5000"
            - name: REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY
              value: "/var/lib/registry"
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
          - name: image-store
            mountPath: "/var/lib/registry"
      volumes:
        - name: image-store
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: registry-pv-claim
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: docker-registry
  namespace: docker-registry
  labels:
    app: docker-registry
spec:
  selector:
    app: docker-registry
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: docker-registry
    name: docker-registry
    namespace: docker-registry
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: example-registry.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: docker-registry
            servicePort: 5000
          path: /
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - example-registry.com
      secretName: tls-secret
```

Comment: you mention you deployed another pod to the cluster, which is normally reached inside but faces the same delay from outside. This indicates a networking issue that needs to be verified first. We need to start from the ground. I'd like to focus first on NodePort since it's the simpler way to expose a service. I'd suggest you to edit you question with the deployment of this pod you are testing and facing the same issue. Also, could you check `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` and check if they are all in `running` state? specially the flannel pods.

Comment: All of those pods are indeed in a running state, and pod networking generally works when it's entirely among pods using the respective cluster IPs of the networks.

Comment: The other pod I was referring to in my original post was just a `sleep` pod that I spawned so I could get a bash session inside the cluster for a minimal working example, but the test had the same results when using a bash session from any pod I happened to have on the cluster.

Comment: @hxtk, could you please share which versions of Kubernetes and Flannel you are using.

Comment: additionally, what backend you configured in your CNI, is it Flannel's default one: vxlan ?

Comment: I apologize for having been unable to answer for the past several days, but the response you posted in that time resolves my issue completely. Thank you for your help. For those who see this question later, I was using kubernetes 1.17, flannel 0.11.0, and, and the vxlan back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future visitors, seems like your issue is related to Flannel.

The whole problem was described here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/88986

https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/1268

including workaround:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/86507#issuecomment-595227060